# way to prevent XSS in restfulwebservices in java

Tags: java, security, xss

I had searched a lot but did not find a good solution for preventing my db to insert scripts in it.

I had tried AntiSamy but not getting how to write the policy file for it, i had also tried pattern matching and it is detecting the pattern i had define but facing the problem with

```
 <a href="javscript:something"></a>
```

I am having pattern ("javascript:") in the defined patterns but it doesn't match the above string. As it is my experience with XSS I am not very famalier with how to write patterns for a given string. What will be the pattern If i want to match if any string contains "javascript:" in it as i mentioned above .

And tell me if there is any easy to use java library available for anti XSS with basic matchs.

Answer (score 1):

XSS in REST, I assume you are rendering some html with some user supplied data embedded in it ? Otherwise it's not XSS but maybe some JSON/XML Injection ? Regardless if you want to filter user supplied input you can use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from apache commons.

I suggest you visit OWASP and read at least: [XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

I do'nt know your requirement, but can't you use httpOnly cookies. This will prevent XSS via malicious javascript injection as those cookies cannot be accessed by javascript.